# Entity Framework v4 examples and tutorials of conceptual model mapping

Tags: orm, entity-framework-4, conceptual

In an application I'm writing I have a fairly complicated Database model. I'd like to use EF4 to map this to a whole lot nicer conceptual model. However all the tutorials I've read are with samples of 2 or 3 tables which all map 1 on 1 to the conceptual model.

I'd like to learn how to correctly map the database model to a different conceptual model using VS 2010. However I can't find any good tutorials or (preferabally) instruction video's.

Somebody got any tips, links or even books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some interesting [mapping scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716779.aspx).

- TPT, TPC, TPH hierarchy mapping
- Entity splitting
- Multiple entity sets per type.